# returning the score with searchkick

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, searchkick

I'm using [SearchKick](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick) with elastic search, and am trying to return the score. For example, if I did a search like this:

```
Profile.search("NYC").first
```

I'm going to get back the record with the highest score that matches that search. I want to also return the score with each record. I know I can grab the searchkick response and parse though it, but is there a faster way to just merge the score into the records that are returned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get all of the Profiles with a corresponding score do this:

```
results = Profile.search("NYC")
results_with_scores = results.zip(results.hits.map{ |hit| hit["_score"] })
```

Now each element of `results_with_scores` will be of the form:

```
 `[Profile_object, corresponding_score]`
```

Answer (score 3):

With SearchKick v2.0.1 or later you can do:

```
Profile.search("NYC").first.search_hit['_score']
```

Comment: search_hit is not working with v3.1.3. I tried using Profile.search("NYC").first.with_hit['_score'] which is raising error